# A error in my Flutter App when i run build_runner

Tags: flutter

When i run flutter pub run build_runner build everything finishes successfuly , but the .g.dart file that should be generated isn't being generated , this is the message i get:

- Deprecated. Use `dart run` instead.
- [INFO] Generating build script completed, took 269ms
- [INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 53ms
- [INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 524ms
- [INFO] Running build completed, took 6.7s
- [INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 35ms
- [INFO] Succeeded after 6.7s with 0 outputs (2 actions)

and this is my code:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:retrofit/retrofit.dart';

import 'package:connectivity_app/features/user_registration/data/models/patient_model.dart';

import '../../../../../core/constants/constants.dart';

part 'patient_api_service.g.dart';

@RestApi(baseUrl: apiBaseUrl)
abstract class PatientApiService {
  factory PatientApiService(Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _PatientApiService;
  @GET('/patientdata')
  Future<HttpResponse<PatientModel>> getPatientData({@Query("id") String? id});
}
```

Can u please help me

I tried different things, i tried using dart run instead i tried using this dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

Comment: what's your file name?

Comment: patient_api_service.dart